# After update I get "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" for any request

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After An update any request to my rails update I get this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Theres nothing obvious in the trace which is:

```
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:54:in `initialize'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:54:in `new'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:54:in `use'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `to_app'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `inject'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `each'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `inject'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/builder.rb:73:in `to_app'
oa-core (0.2.5) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:415:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.4) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:146:in `handle'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:99:in `start'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `each'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `start'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `loop'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `start'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run'
/Users/arcath/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.2.2/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4
```

And the bundle update result was:

```
> bundle update
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using aaronh-chronic (0.3.9) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.4) 
Using builder (2.1.2) 
Using i18n (0.5.0) 
Using activemodel (3.0.4) 
Using erubis (2.6.6) 
Using rack (1.2.2) 
Using rack-mount (0.6.14) 
Using rack-test (0.5.7) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.27) 
Using actionpack (3.0.4) 
Using mime-types (1.16) 
Using polyglot (0.3.1) 
Using treetop (1.4.9) 
Using mail (2.2.19) 
Using actionmailer (3.0.4) 
Installing arel (2.0.10) 
Using activerecord (3.0.4) 
Using activeresource (3.0.4) 
Using addressable (2.2.4) 
Using bundler (1.0.13) 
Using cancan (1.6.4) 
Using coderay (0.9.8) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.2) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.1) 
Using faraday (0.6.1) 
Using growl (1.0.3) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using guard (0.3.4) 
Using guard-rspec (0.3.1) 
Using gyoku (0.4.4) 
Using pyu-ntlm-http (0.1.3.1) 
Using httpi (0.9.4) 
Using railties (3.0.4) 
Using jquery-rails (1.0.5) 
Using meta_search (1.0.5) 
Using meta_where (1.0.4) 
Using mocha (0.9.12) 
Using multi_json (1.0.2) 
Using multi_xml (0.2.2) 
Using mysql (2.8.1) 
Using net-ldap (0.2.2) 
Using nifty-generators (0.4.6) 
Using nokogiri (1.4.4) 
Using nori (0.2.2) 
Using oa-core (0.2.5) 
Using rest-client (1.6.1) 
Using oa-basic (0.2.5) 
Using pyu-ruby-sasl (0.0.3.2) 
Using rubyntlm (0.1.1) 
Using oa-enterprise (0.2.5) 
Using oa-more (0.2.5) 
Using oauth (0.4.4) 
Using oauth2 (0.4.1) 
Using oa-oauth (0.2.5) 
Using ruby-openid (2.1.8) 
Using rack-openid (1.3.1) 
Using ruby-openid-apps-discovery (1.2.0) 
Using oa-openid (0.2.5) 
Using omniauth (0.2.5) 
Using rails (3.0.4) 
Using rb-fsevent (0.4.0) 
Using rspec-core (2.6.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.6.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.6.0) 
Using rspec (2.6.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.6.0) 
Using savon (0.9.2) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.3) 
Installing trainbbcode (1.2.0) 
Using whenever (0.6.7) 
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

My Omniauth Initilaizer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :LDAP, "Ed-ITLDAP", :host => LDAP_HOST, :port => LDAP_PORT, :method => 'plain', :base => LDAP_BASE, :uid =>  'sAMAccountName', :try_sasl => true, :sasl_mechanisms => "GSS-SPNEGO"
end
```

---

Omniauth seems to longer want/need the name of the provider so in my case I removed the "EDITLDAP" option from the provider line like this:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :LDAP, :host => LDAP_HOST, :port => LDAP_PORT, :method => 'plain', :base => LDAP_BASE, :uid =>  'sAMAccountName', :try_sasl => true, :sasl_mechanisms => "GSS-SPNEGO"
end
```

Comment: Could you show us your Omniauth configuration please? It looks to be a problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

@Arcath: check that any middleware you're using is using the right syntax. I had the same problem and the issue was that my config.ru had

```
use Rails::Rack::Static
```

which in Rails 3 is now:

```
use Rack::Static
```

HTH