# getting "OpenSSL read server certificate B: certificate verify failed" error, but ONLY for Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, openssl, omniauth

I have a rails website (reccr.com) that uses omniauth to authenticate users with several different options, including Facebook and Twitter (using OAuth) and a few others (using OpenID). Lately, however, (I think within the last week or so) trying to authenticate via Twitter throws that

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)`

error, but ONLY Twitter does it; every other service authenticates just fine. I've been scouring the internet for a solution, but everything I can find on that error addresses situations where it occurs with ALL authentication providers, and nothing I can find applies to situations where it's only happening with one specific provider.

As far as I know (and I'm the sole developer) nothing had changed about the site that would have predicated this, and I would think that any change to the site that would cause this problem with Twitter would also cause the same problem with Facebook OAuth authentication.

Any ideas on how I can fix this? I was initially hoping that the problem was on Twitter's end and that they'd fix it in a couple of days, but it's been about a week and it's still ongoing, and I haven't seen any other Twitter-specific complaints about this error so I'm starting to suspect it's me after all.

EDIT: OK, after discovering [THIS](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/533) and [THIS](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/404#issuecomment-1715745), I'm halfway there. I'm trying to implement the solution where I add a `:client_options => {:ca_file => '#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt'}` to the end of the line in my omniauth.rb where I declare Twitter as one of my providers. However, when I do that I get a `wrong number of arguments (4 for 3)` error at `lib/rack/builder.rb:54:in`initialize'`. Any ideas how to fix **that**?

Comment: Where did you get your certificate from? Edit: My bad, are you actually connecting through SSL and when is this error thrown, on the callback?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using OmniAuth for authentication, so a lot of that is handled for me; where should I look?

Comment: Ignore that for now, check my answer and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: it looks like this last problem I'm having is similar to this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044667/after-update-i-get-wrong-number-of-arguments-3-for-2-for-any-request

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error means that Ruby cant find the set of certificates on the local machine that verify those provided from the server, see if this blog post can help you out. http://martinottenwaelter.fr/2010/12/ruby19-and-the-ssl-error/

Comment: I have this in my omniauth initializer:

`require "openid/fetchers";
  OpenID.fetcher.ca_file = "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt"`

(and I have my ca-bundle.crt in the right place)

but that's the closest I get to https settings.

Comment: Well there are only two options here. Something is wrong with your ca-bundle and preventing authentication or Twitter is using an invalid certificate. My money is on your ca-bundle, perhaps check to see if they are using a CA not included in your bundle.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it turns out it was a bunch of stuff.

Twitter had changed their SSL certificate, as mentioned [HERE](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/533). (Which I couldn't read last night because dev.twitter.com was down!)

Omniauth uses oauth, which has a bug that forces it to use a specific CA file rather than a more general CA path, as detailed [HERE](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/404#issuecomment-1715745).

One of the solutions is to specify a correct CA file when initializing your provider in omniauth, however I kept getting "wrong number of arguments" errors when I tried to do that. After a long series of mishaps which ended in my completely uninstalling and reinstalling rails, it stopped giving me that error, so I was able to add that specification for omniauth, and now it can authenticate to Twitter again! Hooray!

Unfortunately, somewhere in all of this it stopped being able to authenticate to Facebook, but I'm sure I can figure out why that's happening.